Equation relating Shape Operator, Mean Curvature and Gaussian Curvature
I've been slowly going through a book on Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces. I will admit that when things come to the Shape Operator and the fundamental forms, my understanding is a bit wonky at best. I've been trying to do some examples in the hopes of clearing things up but when I came across this problem I became a bit stumped
Question is as follows:
Let $M$ be an oriented surface with $S_p, K(p), H(p)$ be the shape operator, gaussian curvature and mean curvature respectively at a point $p$ of the surface. Prove that $(S_p)^2 -2H(p)S_p +K(p)Id=0$ Where Id is the standard identity matrix.
I will try to lay out my entire thought process to make sure that I haven't horribly misunderstood something important: $S_p$ is a map from $T_pM$ onto itself. So the shape operator evaluated at p and then squared is a dot product of a vector in $T_pM$ with itself.
$K(p)$ and $H(p)$ are $K_1K_2$ and $K_1/2 + K_2/2$ respectively where $K_1,K_2$ are the principal curvatures of $M$/eigenvalues of the matrix of the shape operator. That would imply that the matrix of the shape operator is $2x2$. Indeed that is later verified in my notes by it being the product of the inverse of the first fundamental quantities matrix and the second fundamental quantities matrix. But what (fairly obvious, I'm certain) things am I missing here? $S_p$ is a linear map from $T_pM$ onto itself, so it can be expressed as $S_p(Z)=A\cdot Z$,$Z$ in $T_pM$. $Z$ and $S_p(Z)$ are both 3-dimensional vectors, so how can A be a $2x2$ matrix?
I'm sure that I'm misunderstanding something rather direly here. Could someone provide a bit help with my conceptual understanding and then some guidance on proving the equation of the original problem?
Thank you kindly.

Regarding dimensions, at each point on a surface, the tangent space is a plane, i.e., $2$-dimensional. If the surface is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then any pair of linearly independent vectors in the plane define the tangent plane via their span even though the vectors themselves have $3$-components. For example, the graph of $z = x^2 + y^2$ has tangent plane at the origin given by the span of $\mathbf{e}_1 = (1, 0, 0)$ and $\mathbf{e}_2 = (0, 1, 0)$.

A completely algebraic fact, independent of the geometry: the characteristic polynomial of a $2 \times 2$-matrix $A$ is $p(t) = t^2 - (\operatorname{tr} A)t + (\det A)$, where $\operatorname{tr}A = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$ and $\det A = \lambda_1 \lambda_2$ are the trace and determinant, respectively. These are essentially Vieta's formulas, once you recognize that the eigenvalues are the roots of the polynomial.

Adding to @SammyBlack’s comment: This is the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem from linear algebra. Nothing particularly to do with geometry.
